# iframe banner: <? if connection timed out then

Tags: php, iframe, connection, conditional-statements

in my site I use iframe to show banner from other site. The problem is, the other site's connection seldom have problem. Now off course at that 'not so frequent' time the empty frame would appear, and it's not good. What I want is have some kind of php if..else conditional statement that can redirect it to other banner. Perhaps (logically) it would be like this:

```
<?php $iframe = the iframe url; $banner = the local banner url;
if ($iframe connection timed out) {$banner;} ?>
```

I am a 100% noob so please help
p

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but are you aware of the term: "bandwidth stealing"?

Comment: Serving banners in iframes is a completely legitimate technique of ad serving. It's likely the "other site" is an ad network who provides an iframe to the publisher/OP for ad serving. I knwo what you are getting at, but I'd say it's unlikely to be the case here.

Comment: Dan is right, I my case, the ad provided by this other site, completely legitimate. As I say, the problem appear when the as serving site has problem in their host or connection. Well it is not unlikely but it happens, perhaps not likely if we are using google ads because their server seldom have this kind of problem. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Will check if it is responding at all, if not don't show the iframe.

Comment: Use a very low timeout to prevent long processing of the PHP though. The script is going to hang everytime while it makes the connection.

Comment: Thank you Dan, this is close enough. I have not tried it yet but considering the low timeout value, as Brendan says, I suspect there will be problem with those who had bad connection rate, like dialups. Anyway if this is the only option, I will use it. Thank you guys

Comment: @Pauro - Dialup should not be an issue as the PHP is executed on the server. All the conditionals happen before the page is sent back to the browser, so it won't make a difference which connection the user is on. You can test timeout values for a variety of servers in order to determine a decent timeout value. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with PHP. You can't have an IF else in the case the other server is replying slowly.

You can append your iframe after onload with javascript (or like google analytics does) to don't slow down your page load time.

Comment: can you be more specific on this? I am a noob :(

Comment: @Pauro yes123 is referring to the difference between Client Side processing where the browser is rendering what you are seeing (HTML, CSS, Javascript) and Server Side where the user has no interaction and everything is processed before it is sent to the client (in your case PHP). An iframe is a HTML construct so PHP has no way of inspecting it because by the time the iframe is constructed, the processing has moved from the server to the client (i.e. PHP's work is done)